# Observable Collections Update Notifications in c#

Tags: c#, events, collections, delegates, observablecollection

I am trying to write a Collection inherited from ObservableCollection which could let me know when my object updates. I know we have a collection changed event but that'll notifies only in case of add and remove and not in update.

So to do that, what I am trying to do is inherit all my working classes(that are used in CustomCollection) from a common class, says EntityBase.

This entity base should have some delegates and events which will be raised by me upon setting or updating some particular properties in my working classes.

And what I want is that event should be handled by my collection.

Code for Entity base is

EntityBase has a delegate and event defined in it.

```
  public delegate void ListNotification(Test obj);
  public event ListNotification SendNotificationToCollection;
```

I am not sure if I am on right track, but if you guys have some better suggestions please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to do this (and I can't imagine why, since it seems bizarre), have your `EntityBase` class implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Your custom collection can subscribe to the `PropertyChanged` event for any items within in. `INotifyPropertyChanged` is provided by the framework for exactly the purpose of informing interested parties that an object has changed in some way. It is used very heavily in `WPF` for example.

Comment: Yeah, I know about INotifyPropertyChanged but not able to understand how it related CustomCollection and EntityBase, Can you please provide some code